# Symfony 3.1 monolog excluded 404

Tags: symfony, monolog

I have a problem with the exclusion of sending mails for common 404 requests. I have setup the following in my config_prod.yml using Symfony 3.1.3 and Monolog 1.21.0, but it keeps sending me the emails when pages are requested. Do I miss something?

[EDIT]
In fact it's a known problem: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/166

```
monolog:
    use_microseconds: false
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler: grouped
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/admin.php
                - ^/administrator
                - ^/blog
                - ^/joomla
                - ^/license
                - ^/phpmyadmin
                - ^/rss
                - ^/sitemap
                - ^/wordpress
                - ^/wp-content
                - ^/wp-login.php
                - ^/xml
        grouped:
            type: group
            members: [streamed, buffered]
        streamed:
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
        buffered:
            type: buffer
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type: swift_mailer
            from_email: 'XXX@YYY.YY'
            to_email: 'XXX@YYY.ZZ'
            subject: An error has occured! [Monolog > config_prod.yml]
            level: debug
```

Comment: have you cleared the cache in prod ? `app/console c:c --env=prod`

Comment: Yes. BTW I didn't know about the shortcut `c:c`. Thanks

Comment: You can use shortcuts with all Symfony commands unless they are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since I tried this, but it might be this setting. Can you try it and let us know the results:

```
swift:
    type: swift_mailer
    from_email: 'XXX@YYY.YY'
    to_email: 'XXX@YYY.ZZ'
    subject: An error has occured! [Monolog > config_prod.yml]
    level: error
```

So change the "level" from "debug" to "error".
Not certain that will work, but try it.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to me that changing level from debug to error will not treat err404 anymore, isn't it? I need to have them treated except certains urls as specified in http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html.

Comment: So, I've just tried it and I still receive mails for both pages (one in the exceptions and one not). The only difference is that in the mail, there is not the information about the requested url, the "request.INFO" part and also the "security.INFO" part.

Comment: In fact it seems that's a known problem https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/166